# TKinter - Pandas dataframe - How to color specific columns?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, tkinter

My script has the following functionalities:

1. The script uses Tkinter to create a GUI for displaying data from an Excel file.
2. It loads the Excel file, creates a window to display the data using a Treeview widget.
3. The window includes search functionality to filter data based on date.
4. Buttons in the window allow users to switch between different views of the data (daily, order, weekly basis).
5. **Cells in the displayed data are colored based on the deviation between actual and forecast values.**
6. The script provides functions for updating and resetting the displayed data.
7. It utilizes pandas for handling Excel data, and matplotlib for creating graphical representations.

**Item 5. does not work as intended. So far I've either managed to color complete rows or nothing at all, while keeping the rest of the code functional, but not a single column or rather the cells in that column.

Now I would like to know whether someone managed to find a way to make that possible with TKinter utilizing the pandas dataframe. I couldn't find a working solution.**

Snippet of the window after pressing the "Tagesbasis"-Button (language is German):

[image]

Calculate the deviation between the "(Ist)" and "Prognose" columns, coloring the "Prognose" cells in green, yellow, or red based on the deviation. Exceptions are made for 0 values, which are colored green.

The console print function for the last 5 rows indicates correct tag distribution, but no coloring is applied for reasons unknown to me:

- Index: 4883, Color: green

- Index: 4884, Color: green

- Index: 4885, Color: green

- Index: 4886, Color: green

- Index: 4887, Color: green

Snippet of the excel chart:
[image]

The relevant code:

```
# Import necessary libraries and modules
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk  # Import themed tk module
from tkcalendar import DateEntry  # Calendar functions
from babel import numbers
import datetime  # Date conversion
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  # Use Tkinter backend for plots
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # Graph functions
import numpy as np  # Graph functions
import matplotlib.dates as mdates  # Date conversion to weekdays
import locale  # X-axis graph labeling in German
from PIL import Image, ImageTk  # Image functions
import pandas as pd  # Import pandas for reading Excel data
from tkinter.ttk import Separator
import mplcursors  # Mouseover over chart points
import warnings  # Filter chart mouseover warnings: "missing pick support for PolyCollection and that the Selection.target.index attribute is deprecated."
import time  # For startup screen progress bar
import threading  # For startup screen progress bar
from functools import partial  # To link the progress bar with loading the DataFrame
from tkinter import messagebox  # For error message (e.g., empty Excel data entry)
import os
import tkhtmlview  # For the datasheet

# Function to handle button click for displaying the data sheet
def on_datenblatt_button_click():
    print("Function started")

    try:
        # Load the Excel file
        file_path = 'data/Input_data.xlsx'  
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path)

        # Check if the window is already open
        if hasattr(on_datenblatt_button_click, 'styled_window') and on_datenblatt_button_click.styled_window.winfo_exists():
            # If yes, close the window
            on_datenblatt_button_click.styled_window.destroy()
            return  # Exit the function to prevent reopening the window

        # Create a new window for the interactive display of the styled DataFrame
        styled_window = tk.Toplevel(start_window)
        styled_window.title("Datasheet")

        # Save the window as an attribute of the function to access it
        on_datenblatt_button_click.styled_window = styled_window

        # Set window size (centered on the screen)
        window_width = 1600
        window_height = 600
        screen_width = styled_window.winfo_screenwidth()
        screen_height = styled_window.winfo_screenheight()
        x_coordinate = int((screen_width - window_width) / 2)
        y_coordinate = int((screen_height - window_height) / 2)
        styled_window.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{x_coordinate}+{y_coordinate}')

        # Create a ttk.Treeview widget
        tree = ttk.Treeview(styled_window)
        tree["columns"] = list(df.columns)
        tree["show"] = "headings"  # Do not display an empty column on the left

        # Add column headers
        for col in df.columns:
            tree.heading(col, text=col)
            tree.column(col, width=100)

        # Pack the Treeview widget
        tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='left')

        # Add scrollbar
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(styled_window, orient='vertical', command=tree.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # Create frame for search
        search_frame = ttk.Frame(styled_window)
        search_frame.pack(side='top', fill='x')

        # Entry for search
        search_entry = ttk.Entry(search_frame)
        search_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        # Bind Enter key for search
        search_entry.bind('<Return>', lambda event: search_data(tree, df, search_entry.get()))

        # Search button
        search_button = ttk.Button(search_frame, text="Search", command=lambda: search_data(tree, df, search_entry.get()))
        search_button.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Empty frame for spacing
        ttk.Frame(search_frame, height=10).grid(row=2, column=0)

        # Buttons for different views
        tagesbasis_button = ttk.Button(search_frame, text="Daily Basis", command=lambda: show_tagesbasis(tree, df))
        tagesbasis_button.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        bestellbasis_button = ttk.Button(search_frame, text="Order Basis", command=lambda: show_bestellbasis(tree, df))
        bestellbasis_button.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        wochenbasis_button = ttk.Button(search_frame, text="Weekly Basis", command=lambda: show_wochenbasis(tree, df))
        wochenbasis_button.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Empty frame for spacing
        ttk.Frame(search_frame, height=10).grid(row=6, column=0)

        reset_button = ttk.Button(search_frame, text="Reset", command=lambda: reset_view(tree, df))
        reset_button.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        # Set colors for cells
        for tag in ['green', 'yellow', 'red']:
            tree.tag_configure(tag, background='')

        # Add entries without coloring
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            values = list(row)
            tree.insert("", tk.END, values=values, iid=index)

            # Select the latest date and save index
            if index == df.index[-1]:
                styled_window.selected_date = row['Datum']
                styled_window.selected_index = index

        # Jump to selection for the latest date
        tree.selection_set(styled_window.selected_index)
        tree.see(styled_window.selected_index)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")

    print("Function ended")

# Function to search data in the Treeview
def search_data(tree, df, search_date):
    try:
        # Convert the date to a string and then search for it
        matching_rows = df.index[df['Datum'].astype(str).str.contains(search_date, case=False, na=False)].tolist()
        if matching_rows:
            tree.selection_set(matching_rows[0])
            tree.see(matching_rows[0])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during search: {e}")

# Function to determine color based on deviation between actual and forecast values
def color_by_deviation(prognose_value, ist_value):
    color = 'green' if ist_value == 0 or prognose_value == 0 else (
        'green' if abs(ist_value - prognose_value) / ist_value <= 0.1 else (
            'yellow' if abs(ist_value - prognose_value) / ist_value <= 0.3 else 'red'
        )
    )
    return color

# Functions to show specific views in the Treeview
def show_tagesbasis(tree, df):
    reset_view(tree, df)
    color_column(tree, df, 'Prognose Verkauf', '(Ist) Bestellung', 'Prognose Bestellung', '(Ist) Woche', 'Prognose Woche')

def show_bestellbasis(tree, df):
    reset_view(tree, df)
    color_column(tree, df, 'Prognose Bestellung', '(Ist) Verkauf', 'Prognose Verkauf', '(Ist) Woche', 'Prognose Woche')

def show_wochenbasis(tree, df):
    reset_view(tree, df)
    color_column(tree, df, 'Prognose Woche', '(Ist) Verkauf', 'Prognose Verkauf', '(Ist) Bestellung', 'Prognose Bestellung',)

# Function to reset Treeview display
def reset_view(tree, df):
    reset_colors(tree)
    show_all_columns(tree, df)
    update_entries(tree, df)

# Function to color a specific column in the Treeview
def color_column(tree, df, target_column, *columns_to_hide):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        color = color_by_deviation(row[target_column], row['(Ist) ' + target_column.split(' ')[1]])

        # Add tags only for the specified column
        tree.item(index, tags=(color,))

        # Console outputs for the first 5 rows
        if index < 5:
            print(f"Index: {index}, Color: {color}")

    # Hide columns
    for col in columns_to_hide:
        tree.column(col, width=0, stretch=tk.NO)

# Function to update Treeview entries
def update_entries(tree, df):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        values = list(row)
        tree.item(index, values=values)

# Function to show all columns in the Treeview
def show_all_columns(tree, df):
    for col in df.columns:
        tree.column(col, width=100, stretch=tk.YES)

# Function to reset cell colors in the Treeview
def reset_colors(tree):
    for tag in ['green', 'yellow', 'red']:
        tree.tag_configure(tag, background='')
```